# Azure App Service with multi-container deployment exposes wrong service

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-appservice

I've deployed a multi-container app to the Azure App Service with a minimalistic docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
 
services:
  backend:
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/backend:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  frontend:
    image: myregistry.azurecr.io/frontend:latest
    ports:
      - "4173:4173"
```

Following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#how-do-i-specify-port-in-my-linux-container-) and considering this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34451) on how to specify non-standard (not 80/8080) ports, I set the `WEBSITES_PORT` value to the frontend port, i.e. 4173.

The deployment is successful, but instead of the frontend, the backend (in that case the Python fastapi swagger) is exposed.

Any ideas on why that is, and how to configure the deployment to show the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a port other than 4173? This port seems to be [classified as reserved](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=1&skey=4&page=40), so Azure may be blocking the allocation.

Comment: Excellent point, thank you! I've been able to get this to work using the "standard" port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#how-do-i-know-which-container-is-internet-accessible-):

> **How do I know which container is internet accessible?**
>
> - Only one container can be open for access
> - Only port 80 and 8080 is accessible (exposed ports)
>
> Here are the rules for determining which container is accessible - in the order of precedence:
>
> - Application setting WEBSITES_WEB_CONTAINER_NAME set to the container name
> - The first container to define port 80 or 8080
> - If neither of the above is true, the first container defined in the file will be accessible (exposed)

More specifically, I switched to using port 8080 for the frontend and changed the order in the docker-compose file to have the frontend service at the top.